# Retriving data on each frame from firebase database takes longer time in unity c#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing a running multiplier game, where I need to store and retrieve every players x,y,z location on each frame on firebase database, say I have 50 frames per second. I am able to save players data on each frame. But while retrieving on each frame it slows down. Say if it takes 0.02 seconds to save and it takes around 0.1 seconds to retrieve. I am using unity as game engine.

```
//for saving - 
var pos = this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localPosition; 
data = new Data (); 
data.x = pos.x; 
data.y = pos.y; 
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson (data); 
reference.Child ("users").Child ("4444").SetRawJsonValueAsync (json); 

//for retrieving - 
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance 
.GetReference ("users/4444") 
.GetValueAsync ().ContinueWith (task => { 
  if (task.IsFaulted) { 
    // Handle the error... 
  } else if (task.IsCompleted) { 
    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result; 
    if (snapshot == null) { 
    Debug.Log ("snapshot is null"); 
  } else { 
    json = snapshot.GetRawJsonValue ().ToString (); 
    data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data> (json); 
  }
```

So I need other players location info on each frame. If I limit my frames to 10 or less it works fine, but again that doesn't makes sense for a online multiplier game. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? If you want your game to run at X frames per second, you will need to render a frame every 1/X seconds. This can mean that certain operations are too expensive and impractical to run in a real-time application.

Comment: One would not get a single value from a database but get maybe 1000 at once, then process them and while doing that, get the next ones. Same for saving I'd say.